# Transferring through Hamad International Airport (Doha)

Tags: layovers, qatar-airways, qatar, doh

I am gonna fly to Sydney next month by Qatar Airways. After the first flight, I will arrive at Hamad International Airport (First, I am flying from my country to Doha by Qatar Airways and then after connection time at Hamad International Airport, I will fly to Sydney, again by Qatar Airways). Note that I booked the two flight at the same time and I have one booking code for both. Regarding the transfer, I have some questions?

1) Do I have to collect my baggage at baggage claim and check them again at Hamad International Airport?

2) Do I have to check in again and receive another boarding pass for the onward flight?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this for a single reservation with Qatar airways?

Comment: There are multiple separate questions, here. 2 and 3 are OK together but 1 needs to be separate as it doesn't really have anything to do with the others. Actually, I don't know what you mean in your first question. The answer to 2 and 3 will depend on whether you're flying on one ticket to Sydney or you have separate tickets to Doha and from Doha to Sydney, and you haven't told us that.

Comment: I've heard at Hamad International Airport different colors are used for different purposes. For example, for transfers yellow is used on signs and boarding passes. These different colors help passangers to easily follow the signs and get to the right halls or gates.@DavidRicherby

Comment: First, I am flying from my country to Doha by Qatar Airways and then after connection time at Hamad International Airport, I will fly to Sydney, again by Qatar Airways.@JacobHorbulyk. @DavidRicherby

Comment: OK but is it one ticket or two? This makes a big difference: if it's two tickets, you'll need to check in again at Doha; if it's one ticket, you won't. If you booked both halves of the flight at the same time and have a single booking code, it wll be oen ticket.

Comment: It's one ticket

Answer (score 1):

For (1), **No**, your luggage will be checked through.
For (2), **Probably not**. You usually get both boarding passes at your initial check-in, even if that is online. Rarely, you will not have an assigned seat on the second flight, and the pass will direct you to see an agent at the connecting airport. In no case do you have to exit to landside; Doha's website says every terminal has a Transfer Desk to handle boarding pass re-issue, as well as missed flights.